# Prestashop install error - Configure shop information

Tags: prestashop

I'm installing prestashop 1.6.1.10 on ubuntu/xenial64 (vagrant).

I get error on Configure shop information - An error occurred during installation...

In the log I see:

```
[Tue Feb 14 08:27:12.364749 2017] [:error] [pid 7587] [client 55.55.56.1:49446] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PrestaShopException: Property Currency->decimals is not valid in /vagrant/prestashop/classes/ObjectModel.php:909
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/prestashop/classes/LocalizationPack.php(299): ObjectModelCore->validateFields()
#1 /vagrant/prestashop/classes/LocalizationPack.php(68): LocalizationPackCore->_installCurrencies(Object(SimpleXMLElement), true)
#2 /vagrant/prestashop/install/models/install.php(549): LocalizationPackCore->loadLocalisationPack('<?xml version="...', '', true)
#3 /vagrant/prestashop/install/controllers/http/process.php(207): InstallModelInstall->configureShop(Array)
#4 /vagrant/prestashop/install/controllers/http/process.php(93): InstallControllerHttpProcess->processConfigureShop()
#5 /vagrant/prestashop/install/classes/controllerHttp.php(173): InstallControllerHttpProcess->process()
#6 /vagrant/prestashop/install/index.php(31): InstallControllerHttp::execute()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /vagrant/prestashop/classes/ObjectModel.php on line 909, referer: http://dev.imagine-lotus.design/install/index.php?restart=true
```

What can it be?

I've installed this same code, on the same ubuntu image before and it was OK.

EDIT:

I by-pass this issue by commenting out /classes/ObjectModel.php:909

I will un comment it after install is done

NOTE: after install an error in the front, I had to create a currency in the backend to solve it

I'm still getting errors, I noticed that prestashop was installed with multi-language, which is different than previous installation.

In the install process I didn't choose to install other language than EN,
Maybe chrome passes some variable that presta recognize as my native language and tries to install, and fails

Answer (score 1):

I by-pass this issue by commenting out /classes/ObjectModel.php:909

I will un comment it after install is done

NOTE: after install an error in the front, I had to create a currency in the backend to solve it

I'm still getting errors, I noticed that prestashop was installed with multi-language, which is different than previous installation.

In the install process I didn't choose to install other language than EN, Maybe chrome passes some variable that presta recognize as my native language and tries to install, and fails

so I Use Firefox instead of chrome and solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while installing Prestashop 1.7 on **licalhost xampp**. But in my case, I did not even get the error log to find out the error, moreover, the installation request was being made via AJAX so error identification was tough, but after more research,  I found out the source of the error.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\localizationPack.php

I used

> "try" and "catch"

to identify the error. The error is originating from

> C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\vendor\icanboogie\cldr\lib\webProvider.php

as a result of network problem. Here, the script needs to send a **cURL** request to an online location, so if there is no internet connection, it shows that error.

After finding this out, I connected to a connection and tried it again and it worked perfectly.

Try that too.

Hope it works as it did for me.